# reduce the a if-elif-else code in a function

Tags: python

I was writing a code using python. I am using if-elif-else condition. The code is not looking good. Is there any other way to write the code?

```
def my_fun(x):
    if x<=200:
        x=0.2
    elif 201<=x<=300:
        x=0.3
    elif 301<=x<=400:
        x=0.4
    elif 401<=x<=500:
        x=0.5  
    elif 501<=x<=600:
        x=0.6
    elif 601<=x<=700:
        x=0.7
    elif 701<=x<=800:
        x=0.8
    elif 801<=x<=900:
        x=0.9
    elif 900<=x<=1000:
        x=1
    else:
        x=1.5 
    return x
courier_invoice['x_weight_slab'] = courier_invoice['weight by company'].apply(my_fun)
```

Is there any other way to write this function?

Comment: Is `x` always expected to be an integer like `201`, or might the input be a floating-point number like `200.5`?

Comment: actually, if x is between 201 and 300,  then needs to return the value 0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this function which will calculate the value and return
it by rounding up to 1 decimal point

```
def func(x):
    if x <= 200:
        return .2;
    elif x <= 1000:
        return round(((x+99) // 100) * 0.1, 1);
    return 1.5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import math
def my_fun(x):
    x = -x
    if x >= -200:
        return 0.2
    elif x >= -1000:
        return -math.floor(x/100)/10
    return 1.5
```